# Creating and editing text in Word document in C#

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have used itextsharp for PDF documents and now I need to create and add a text to a Word document(I'm using OpenXml SDK) so I would like to know what classes and objects are used here to add a paragraph or to set the alingment and indentation or to set the basefont and size of font. For example, this is my code for creating PDF using iTextSharp and now I want to translate it to create Word:

```
 Document document = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 40, 40, 50, 50);
 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(pdfFile.FileName, FileMode.Create));
 document.Open();

 document.NewPage();
 Paragraph title = new Paragraph("aaa",titleFont);
 title.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
 document.Add(title);
 document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

 Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("",Font11);
 p1.IndentationLeft = 20f;
 document.Add(p1);
```

Comment: The OpenXML SDK is only a very thin wrapper around the Xml, so you'll just do something very similar to the code for the Pdf. But you'll need to save the document at the end.

Comment: Can you please be more specific, what are the key words i have to use etc.

Comment: Did you check the documentation that comes with the SDK? It comes with great examples! See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/cc850833.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is have I done it with DocX.dll:

```
var document = DocX.Create(wordFile.FileName);

Novacode.Paragraph title = document.InsertParagraph("AAA", false, titleFormat);
title.Alignment = Alignment.center;
document.InsertParagraph(Environment.NewLine);

document.Save();
Process.Start("WINWORD.exe", wordFile.FileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to discover the things you ask about is to download the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool from Microsoft's site. Create a small, sample document in Word (as a user), save it, close it, then open it in the Productivity Tool. That can show you both the underlying XML as well as standard code for generating the document. That way you can see what objects are used and how they're put together.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But, in the meanwhile, I have found a library called docX. For me, it's a bit simplier and i figured it out very quick.